# why there is no difference between initialization and assignment for the build-in type in C?

Tags: c++, c, initialization

I am reading a book and it says that there is no difference between initialization and assignment for the built-in type in `C` or `C++`, but the type like `string` in `C++`, there are difference. Why? Why there is no difference for the built-in types in `C`?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. C rules need not apply to C++ or vice versa.

Comment: For built-in types, it's more or less the same in both languages. C++ allows you to make them different for user-defined types (by defining your own constructor and/or assignment operator), while C doesn't.

Comment: There _is_ a difference between initialization and assignment in both languages, depending on the variable's scope. Variables with static storage duration are initialized before main() is called, and they are guaranteed to be initialized. Initialization and assignment of such variables occur in different places of the code, at very different points in the execution time.

Comment: C++'s class `string` is not a "build-in" type.

Answer (score 5):

Because the standard types like `int` don't have constructors. These

```
int x = 123;
int y;
y = 123;
```

are the same (at the beginning, `y` will have some random/garbage value).

While creating an object will call its constructor. So, for example:

```
std::string s = "123";
std::string y;
y = "123";
```

`s` will be created and initialized immediately, while `y` will be created, its values will be initialized (based on `std::string`'s constructor) and later, they will be changed during the `operator=`.

Comment: This is true for C, but false for C++.  `int x = 123; int y; y = 123;` are different things in C++.

Comment: @delnan - exactly my point, too. Even though James' note was something new to me. I didn't ask for clarification, because I read his answer below.

Answer (score 4):

C doesn't really have the distinction between initialization and
assignment; in C, the first assignment can be considered
initialization, and:

```
int a = 42;
```

and

```
int a;
a = 42;
```

are basically identical.

In C++, initialization and assignment *are* different, even for
the most basic types.  Consider:

```
int
main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    switch ( argc ) {
    case 1:
        int a = 42;
        //  ...
        break;
    default:
        //  ...
    }
}
```

This is illegal in C++.  On the other hand:

```
int
main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    switch ( argc ) {
    case 1:
        int a;
        a = 42;
        //  ...
        break;
    default:
        //  ...
    }
}
```

is legal.  The rule is that no code can "jump over" the
initialization to a point where the variable would still be
in scope, but it can jump over a definition which contains no
initialization.

Of course, it's hard to imagine the compiler generating
different code for initialization and assignment of an `int`,
but they remain formally distinct.

Comment: Interesting case. I thought you must always enclose the "body" of a `case` with `{}` when you define a variable (for example, the illegal example in your answer is "fixed" if `{}` are added)

Comment: @KirilKirov The semantics of a `switch` are really just those of a calculated `goto`.  (Look up Duff's device, for example.)

Answer (score 1):

Built-in primitives of C++ all have very simple structure: each one is stored in a single contiguous block of memory. To initialize or to assign such primitive you need to copy the content of a new value taken in its entirety into the memory region occupied by the primitive. No other action is necessary. The old value is always destroyed by this action, be it a previously assigned value or a garbage left in an uninitialized portion of memory.

Classes, on the other hand, may have very complex structure. They may have pointers to other objects, and hold resources that need to be released when a new value is assigned to the object of that class. When you perform initialization, you know that the object does not hold other objects or resources yet, so nothing needs to be released. However, when you assign an existing object, the resources and objects that it holds may need to be released. That is why assignment is different from initialization for non-primitives.

Answer (score 1):

The standard datatypes dont have constructors. So when you say,

```
int a = 2;
```

then a variable will have value as 2.

and when you say,

```
int b;
b = 5;
```

then when b is created it will have some garbage value and later on it will be assigned the new value i.e 5.

This is not the case for std::string. Because it has constructor, so when you create an object of class string then it will be created using its constructor.

```
string str = "sample";
```

`str` will be created with value sample using string's parametrized constructor.

```
string str1;
str1 = "sample2";
```

`str1` will be created as empty string using string's default constructor and then assigned new value using the assignment operator of string.

Answer (score 1):

[Kiril Kirov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18870631/1149736) already explained why initialization and assignment are the same for standard types, but I'd like to give you practical example what's get called when, so let's play:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class A {
protected:
    int x;

public:
    A()
    {
        cout << "Constructor" << endl;
    }

    A(int val)
    {
        x = val;
        cout << "Parametrized constructor with x=" << x << endl;
    }

    A(const A& o)
    {
        cout << "Copy constructor with x=" << o.x << endl;
        x = o.x;
    }

    ~A()
    {
        cout << "Destructor for x=" << x << endl;
    }

    A &operator=(int val)
    {
        cout << "Assigning value x=" << val << endl;
        x = val;
        return *this;
    }

    A &operator=(const A& o)
    {
        // You are required to free previously allocated resources
        // if you're not going to reuse them
        cout << "Assigning value from parent object x=" << o.x << endl;
        x = o.x;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a = 1;
    A b;
    b = 2;
    A c = a;
    b = a;
    A d(4);

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Will result into:

```
Parametrized constructor with x=1
Constructor
Assigning value x=2
Copy constructor with x=1
Assigning value from parent object x=1
Parametrized constructor with x=4

Destructor for x=4
Destructor for x=1
Destructor for x=1
Destructor for x=1
```

So to sum up:

- `A a = 1;` - will call parametrized constructor
- `A b;` - will call empty constructor
- `b = 2;` - will call assign value operator
- `A c = a;` - will call copy constructor
- `b = a;` - will call assign object operator
- `A d(4);` - will call parametrized constructor